# How to scroll to the bottom of console window in PyCharm2019 automatically?

Tags: debugging, scroll, pycharm, console, auto

I want to make my Python IDE->PyCharm, to scroll to the bottom of console window  automatically,so that I can watch the latest output messages of my running code.[image]